# How to set value as an Object in JS ES6 new Map (key, value) pair

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've finished my first small Vue project and my senior told me to re-write it with the new hardcoded data structure using new Map(key-value pair); and value as objects.

JS and Vue are new things for me so I've looked it up a lot and saw some comments that the structure I need to do is impossible. However our company uses data structure like that and I need to it...

what I'm trying to do is a simple book list app. 5 people can add book(s) per year and it has to be sorted by the year. The scope of sorting is getting corresponding data when any year in calendar is clicked.

I used filter() but he said adding same data(year) into an Object in Array is a bad idea because it will make slow the process. We deals with Big and Real time data. update cycle is 1 sec, 24/7/365.

If it's impossible then could you please let me know any hints to do it right??

```
var books = new Map();
books.set(['2018', {'a' : {id: 'userid', name: 'a'}, 'b': {id: userid, name: 'b'}}], ['2019', {'a': {{id: 'userid', name: 'a'}, 'b': {id: userid, name: 'b'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll ignore the syntax errors (missing brackets and unquoted id values) assuming this is not copied from your actual code.

You can use the `Map()` *constructor* with an iterable like an array to set multiple elements during initialization like

```
let map = new Map([
  ['2018',  { foo: 'bar }],
  ['2019',  someVariable]
]);
```

You *cannot* do the same with `Map.prototype.set()`.

So while you could do it like this

```
let books = new Map([[
  '2018', {'a' : {id: 'userid', name: 'a'}}
], 
[
  '2019', {'a': {id: 'userid', name: 'a'}}
]])
```

your senior (and soon you) is probably gonna be very happy if you start breaking things down into very explicit, small and manageable steps instead of throwing it all into one long line.

Give an approach like this a try and see how you like it

```
let books = new Map()
books.set('2018', {'a' : {id: 'userid', name: 'a'}})
books.set('2019', {'a' : {id: 'userid', name: 'a'}})
```

Comment: Thanks but what I didn't understand about this new Map is that it's not possible to store value as objects. I need to have 1 key '2018' and 5 people's info in values.. is it possible...?

Comment: The value *is* an object in the new map, since you specified it as an object: `{'a' : ... }`. You can populate the object completely in the initial `set` call i.e. `{ 'a': person1data, 'b': person2data, ...}` or `get` it later from the map and add additional properties to the object.

Comment: Very clear. I got the working structure now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Example using Map() in VueJS.

```
export default {
  ...
  data: function() {
    return {
      books: new Map([
        ["2018", { a: { id: "userid", name: "a" } }],
        ["2019", { b: { id: "userid", name: "b" } }]
      ])
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.books.forEach((dict, year) => {
      for (const key in dict) {
        const obj = dict[key];
        console.log(`O:--Get Book Info--:year/${year}:id/${obj.id}:name/${obj.name}`);
      }
    });
  }
};
```